# Unity. Как сослаться на компонент объекта вложенного в объект, вложенного в объект?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть игровой объект примерно такой структуры:

```
Player
    >BodyParts
    WeaponHolder
        >Gun1
        >Gun2
        >Gun3
```

Как я могу сослаться на компонент объекта `Gun1` в скрипте объекта `Player`, не используя public GameObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Transform[] Childrens = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
foreach (Transform children in Childrens)
    if (children.gameObject.name == "Gun1") {
        // Do something
        break;
    }
```

Но это ужасное профанство. По нормальному:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject[] _guns;
```

Comment: Ответ хороший только не `children.GameObject...` а `children.gameObject...`

Comment: Чего в первом подходе профанского? Что то, что это - вполне адекватные решения.

Comment: Странная ситуация, отсутствия ссылкии на дочерний объект, который либо в префабе, либо заспавнен по идее материнским и в отсутствие ссылки использовать множественный GetComponent, который вообщето грузный. Ну что-то явно не так. Большее профанство только поиск по сцене через тег или по имени.

Comment: Вручную каждый раз перетаскивать всех детей в инспекторе - маразм, такой код в условном `Start`'е при загрузке сцены вообще никак не повлияет на производительность. Да и взаимосвязь потомок-родитель прописана в сериализованном представлении этого объекта, зачем сериализовывать эти данные еще раз, но в виде массива, если можно просто достать их в рантайме?

Comment: Ага, пройдёт неделя, две, он переименует Gun1 в Shotgun, Gun2 в Rocketlouncher и опа. Нихрена не работает.

Comment: Что мешает сериализовать имя?